# Output of a certain attribute in a ThenInclude statement (EFCore)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, include

After connecting several tables with Include, I only want to add the 'Name' attribute from the 'Tag' table

```
var result = context.RssChannels
                    .Include(rsschannel => rsschannel.Articles)
                        .ThenInclude(arttag => arttag.ArticleTags)
                            .ThenInclude(tag => tag.Tag.Name)
                    .Include(rsschannel => rsschannel.Articles)
                        .ThenInclude(Rating => Rating.Rating)
                            .ToList();
```

[image]

```
public partial class Tag
    {
        public Tag()
        {
            ArticleTags = new HashSet<ArticleTag>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }
    }
```

Is it possible to add only individual attributes from a linked table

Answer (score 0):

The method `ThenInclude` must use only to include navigation properties, so if you want to specify one property from the navigation property, you should create a `Select` before the materialization (it means, before calling some of the methods `FirstOrDefault`, `SingleOrDefault`, `ToList`, etc).

Furthermore, if you use the `Select` method, you don't need to use the `Include`, because the ef core automatically uses eager loading when some data projection like `Select` are used;